# Is it possible to run (via maven) select junit selenium tests based on a custom annotation

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

Tried to get all the good keywords in the question. Basically I have a number of selenium tests, using JUnit4/Maven and created a custom annotation to markup each test with some basic info:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TestInfo {
public enum Priority { LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH }

Priority priority() default Priority.LOW;
String useCase() default "";
String createdBy() default "unknown";
String lastModified() default "unknown";
}
```

So each test looks like this:

```
@Test
@TestInfo(priority = TestInfo.Priority.HIGH,
        createdBy = "MivaScott",
        lastModified = "2016/11/29",
        useCase = "Log into website with valid credentials")
public void loginValidCredentials() throws Exception {
    Properties user = Data.getUserCredentials("default");
    loginPage.setLogin(user.getProperty("username"));
    loginPage.setPassword(user.getProperty("password"));
    loginPage.clickSignInButtonAndWait();
    Verify.titleContains(MyConstants.TITLE_DASHBOARD, "");
}
```

What I'm hoping for is that I can specify on the command like to only run tests that are marked as being HIGH priority. So something to the effect of:

`mvn -DTestInfo.priority=HIGH test`

Is this possible, or something similar?

Comment: Are you using junit4? If so you should have a look at Categories. Solves your requirement of running tests based on a annotation out of the box. https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories

Comment: @Grasshopper, I saw categories in my looking for answers (haven't research how they work yet). I was really hoping to not have to add another annotation/thing-to-remember. I'm developing this framework for non-coders so the less moving parts the better. But yes, that is the fallback option.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways I can think to resolve this.

> > Create a custom test runner that parses your system property and only runs test methods with the matching annotation.

```
public class PrioritzedTestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {


@Override
protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
    String priority = System.getProperty("TestInfo.priority");
    TestInfo info = method.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);

    if (priority == null || info == null) {
        //If the configuration is blank or the test is uncategorized then run it
        super.runChild(method, notifier);
    } else if (priority != null) {
       //try to resolve the priority and check for a match.
        TestInfo.Priority configPri = TestInfo.Priority.valueOf(priority.toUpperCase());
        if (info.equals(configPri)) {
            super.runChild(method, notifier);
        }
    }
    }
```

You would need to add the RunWith annotation to your test classes.

```
@RunWith(PrioritizedTestRunner.class)
 public voidMyTestClass() {
  @Test
  @TestInfo(...)     
  public void testThing1(){} 
  @Test
  @TestInfo(...)     
  public void testThing2(){}
}
```

---

> > If The tests are fairly static, separate them into classes rather than annotations and use a custom maven profile to execute the test collection based on commonly-named files or resources.

I haven't configured this myself, but I've seen it done.  you should be able to have maven test-phases targeting your PriorityLevels.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

at which point you should be able to execute each priority level as a separate mvn command, if I'm reading the documentation correctly.

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe this feature can be implemented by using tags in your junit test cases.

@WithTag(type="epic", name="Audit")

Reference: http://thucydides.info/docs/thucydides/_adding_tags_to_test_cases.html

Comment: The @WithTag annotation is an annotation added by the Thucydides library, and is not part of the default JUnit 4 API.  An additional test-scope library would be needed to use this feature.